# Break a loop without exiting script (bash)

Tags: bash, loops

I want to run a loop that iterates over a list of users and performs an action if both of two checks pass. Each check is written as a function that returns a yes or no depending on whether the check passes or not. Right now I have it set up like this:

```
for User in Users
 do
   check_1
   check_2
   if [[ check_1 = yes ]] && [[ check_2 = yes ]]
   then
      perform some function
   fi
done
```

I would like to keep each check as a function, rather than writing them explicitly into the for loop as they are quite verbose and that would make for quite a nasty nest of ifs, fors, and whiles. I was wondering if there was some way I could do away with the if statement so that each check would continue the function if it passed or move on to the next user if it did not so that the code would function like this;

```sh
for user in users
 do
    check_1
    check_2
    some_function
 done
```

Inuitively I feel that this is better code-style. Am I correct? Is this feasible? Is there a better way?

EDIT: I am closing this question because it seems to have resulted from a fundamental misunderstanding of the bash. Sorry, its been a while.

Comment: You mean like `check_1 && check_2 && somefunction`?

Comment: Is there some reason you want the code to *"...look like this"*, or do you want it to "*...function like this*"?

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica thanks for pointing out the ambiguity, fixed.

Comment: That's better. Either way works just as well. The *compound command* shown above only executes `check_2` on successful return from `check_1`; and only executes `somefunction` on successful return of `check_2`. (basically, the compound command stops executing after a failure of any command contained within it and would simply loop getting the next user). Setting a `trap` on `ERR` will also do the same.

Comment: Thank you @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica. The checks do not return a non zero exit status, but rather set a variable equal to either "yes" or "no" based on if the value of another variable matches what is expected. Maybe I will use a nonsense command in the checks instead such as `if $var != expected_value; then asdf ; fi` (simplified for brevity). That would return a non-zero exit status. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `check_1`, `check_2`, etc. are commands that return with non-zero statuses on failure; an ERR trap might help. E.g:

```
trap continue ERR

for user in users; do
    check_1
    check_2
    ...
done

trap - ERR
```